# How to increment a number and output to label

Tags: c#-4.0

The program should count the number of correct words typed (duh), and after 60 seconds, print that value to a little label.

Does it? No. It counts to 1 and then refuses to increment.

But (and this is the fun part) when I run it in Debug mode with a breakpoint, it all works fine.

I can only figure it is some sort of variable encapsulation error (which still makes no sense).

Here's a little snippet:

```
 private void checkWord()
    {
        if (txtInput.Text.ToLower() == lblQuery.Text.ToLower())
        {
            score++;
        }
    }
```

And here is the whole source because why not...

Programming Project.zip

http://tinyurl.com/c4af2nd

Comment: 1) Believe it or not, that is the relevant code
2) The link itself is right below the name of the files

Comment: It's not supposed to be... click the blu glowing tinyURL link. Also, what are you planning to do with a phone? read the .cs files? Good luck...

Comment: It's clickable now because @Mark hall edited your question and fixed it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are getting white space in your comparison string. Try this to see if it works.

```
private void checkWord()
{
    if (txtInput.Text.ToLower().Trim() == lblQuery.Text.ToLower())
    {
        score++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to amuse myself, I tried it. And by the gods it worked. Tell me Mark... will you marry me?

Comment: @user2297502 I believe that you are getting the white space when you are hitting the spacebar to go to next the next word, when you are debugging it appears that the timing changes just enough to work. And I think my wife would probably object :)